# Why inventor will use "consisting" instead of "comprising" transitional phrase in a patent claim?

Tags: patentability, claims, claim-construction, transitional-phrase

**Why inventor will use "consisting" instead of "comprising" transitional phrase in a patent claim?**

If a transitional phrase, "comprising" covers broader scopes than a transitional phrase, "consisting", then why on earth an inventor will use "consisting" transitional phrase in his/her patent claim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid prior art. If you invent a 3 wheel car and you say “comprising 3 wheels” you have not specified a 3 wheel car since comprising is open ended you have essentially said “at least 3 wheels”. Consisting of 3 wheels narrows to avoid the prior art.  There are better examples but fundamentally cliam scope is a balance. Claim too much and it’s already been done, claim too narrow and get designed around.